# Prove where $|x|^2(\sin(\pi|x|))^2$ (piecewise) is differentiable in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives, continuity, partial-derivative

List all points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ at which $f$ is differentiable as well as ALL points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ where $f$ is not differentiable (implied by the first list) when

\begin{equation}
   f(x) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       |x|^2(\sin(\pi|x|))^2 & \text{ if } x \in \mathbb{Q}^2\\
       0 & \text{otherwise}
     \end{array}
   \right.
\end{equation}

**Solution**
So I know this function is only continuous at those places where the function takes on the value $0$ for rational values of $x$, because for all the irrationals it's $0$. Then I think, where is the function $0$ for rational $x$? That's at $x=0$ and where $\sin(\pi |x|)^2=0$, i.e. for all integer multiples of $\pi$. Therefore where the euclidean length $|x|$ is an integer. This gives a bunch of concentric circles where the function is continuous.

Now I just need to write this set of points and prove it is **differentiable** at these points (I know it can't be differentiable anywhere else because it needs to be continuous in order to be differentiable). Can anyone help me prove that the function is differentiable at these circles where it is continuous? Thanks!

Edit: To prove $f$ is differentiable where it is continuous, that means showing either showing there exists a linear map $A$ such that $\displaystyle\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{|f(x+h)-f(x)-Ah|}{|h|}=0$, or else showing all of the partial derivatives exist and are continuous... My prof gave a hint that $0\leq \sin(t)\leq t$ for all $t\in[0,\pi/2]$.

Still haven't figured this one out... Thank you for your help!

Comment: Is there a mistake in your definition of $\mathrm{f}$? Did you mean to type $x \in \mathbb{Q}^2$? I suspect that you want ${\bf x} \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and to write $\|{\bf x}\|$. The notation $x$ and $|x|$ implies, to me at least, that $x$ is a real (resp. rational) number and that $|x|$ is its absolute value.

Comment: Sorry, where is the mistake? Yes, it is piecewise depending on whether $x\in\mathbb{Q}^2$ or not.

Comment: The notation $x$ and $|x|$ is often used for a number and its absolute value. A more common notation for a vector is ${\bf x}$ and $\|{\bf x}\|$ for its magnitude. That's why I was confused.

Comment: Oops! Yes, sorry. This is the notation my professor uses and it confuses me too. I've seen $||x||$ before for length and I like it better! Here everywhere you see $|x|$ it means the euclidean distance (norm) of $x$.

Comment: Wikipedia uses *our* preferred notation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29#Euclidean_norm

Comment: Still trying to show it's differentiable on the set where it's continuous. Made an edit with more info, can you take a look? Thanks!

Comment: You can just remove that troubling || as the terms are already squared.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Then I get the sum of the squares of the 2 components of $x$. Can you see if this helps?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest changing coordinates to $x=r\cos \theta, y = r\sin \theta$. This will make it easier to find the partial derivatives which are tangent and perpendicular to the concentric circles. Thus:

\begin{equation}
   f(r) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       r^2(\sin(\pi r))^2 & \text{ if } r^2 \in \mathbb{Q}\\
       0 & \text{otherwise}
     \end{array}
   \right.
\end{equation}

Which is a function of $r$ only. Since any change in $h$ in the $\theta$ has no effect on $f$, we can take $h$ to be a scalar:
$$f'(n)=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(n+h)-f(n)-Ah}{h}$$
And use the fact that: 
$$\sin(n\pi+h)-\sin(h)=\sin(h) (-1)^{n}$$

Comment: Thanks! So the best strategy is to try to find the partial derivatives and show they are continuous? Then quote a theorem which says partial derivatives existing and being CONTINUOUS implies differentiability? Thanks you for your help!! (P.S. I noticed you changed $\mathbb{Q}^2$ to $\mathbb{Q}$. I'm trying to digest this but I'm REALLY bad at polar coordinates.)

Comment: @Mathemanic - since $r$ is a number, not a vector, it cannot belong to $\mathbb{Q}$. Also, $r$, being a square root may not be rational, but if $x$ and $y$ are both rational, then so will $r^2$.